# How to searching result dependent on query Result

Tags: query

I have a problem. In my scenario, I want to search something in my query result.

```
list<Account> acc = Database.query(select id, name from account);
```

And i want to search somethings in this list.

how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to iterate the list and compate the fields with your search parameter:

```
list<Account> acc = Database.query(select id, name from account);

for(Account a : acc){
    if(a.Field1__c == 'YourSearchParameter'){
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, i want to in the vf page and in the Name column header, input "a", and the table will change and display all name like"a%". Just like this.  how to do this?

Comment: Well, for that just check this wonderfull article from Jeff: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/13/building-a-dynamic-search-page-in-visualforce/